# 3001番ポートで開いたはずなのに開けない

Tags: node.js, network

こんにちは
さくらサーバ上で3001番ポートにExpressフレームワークをおいて、アクセスできるようにしたはずなのですが、最初の一回目に成功したあと、もう一度アクセスしようとすると、なぜか反応がありません。その他の3000番ポートにおいたものは普通にアクセスできるようになってます。
また、iptablesでも3001番は普通にあけてあります。

何か心当たりのある方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: 一回目に成功したのは、どのような操作だったのでしょうか？　「反応がありません」というのは、具体的にはどのような状況なのでしょうか？　一回目のアクセスでExpressフレームワークの処理が始められ、それが終わっていないという状況ではありませんか？　サーバー上でExpressフレームワークのプロセスがCPUを大量消費したり、多数の関連プロセスが生成されてはいませんか？

Comment: Fumu7さん
ご返答ありがとうございます。
一回目も二回目以降も、普通にファイルをアップロードした後に、そのファイルの階層まで行ってnpm startしただけです。

ちなみにOSはCentOS6.7です。